# Multiple JVM instances in one program

Tags: java, jvm

I have a `JFrame` and a `JTabbedPane`

The `JTabbedPane` has `JPanel`s, and each `JPanel` has an `Applet`.

If I load the applet, and then close it, the CPU usage drops but the RAM usage stays high. So in order for me to correctly release the RAM, each `JPanel`/`Applet` has to have its own JVM which I can terminate. The code of the `Applet` isn't mine, but that's how it was made, simply destructing it won't work.

So what I'm asking is, how can I attatch a new JVM to each `JPanel` as I add one?

Comment: Are you sure this is what is going on? Don't you have a memory leak? Did you try to run a profiler to see if some objects do not stay in memory?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure.  The applet is made like that so it only frees up after the JVM is destroyed.

Comment: What kind of memory does the applet hold that is not released once the applet object is garbage-collected (which should happen soon after you close the panel or you can request it)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this you would need to have a wrapper application capable of starting a new instance of the JVM (forking a new process) each time you want to open one of your JPanel/Applet things.  You could do this by calling `Runtime.exec()` and invoking a new instance of the JVM, but honestly all of this smells a little bit to me.  The JVM really isn't designed for this and I think what's more likely is you have a memory leak somewhere that isn't properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have more than 1 instance of the JVM running for any given application, as detailed by the [Runtime Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)

However, I believe if you remove all of your references to each Applet when you shut it down, you can call System.gc() to clean up the memory so that you can use it for something else within that Java application. However, keep in mind that your RAM usage will not go down, as the JVM heap is allocated at startup and, so far as I know, cannot be resized during execution. For information on how that works, see [JVM Option: Xmx Allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731809/jvm-option-xmx-allocation)